Guidelines for image detection model for static sample
I  have 20,000 plus images of art (paintings, sculptures, jars, etc) stored in a data base. The actual pieces are distributed in multiple warehouses. Ideally, the physical pieces SHOULD have a sticker (with its ID's, QR code, etc), those stickers are made of paper, so the could suffer damaged, be poorly printed, unreadable, be completely missing or even mislocated. My goal is creating a model that receives an input (image sent by someone from any warehouse), identifies the exact same piece of art from the available data and returns its id, details, etc.
In my case, the sample is static, fixed (there will not be "new" art pieces, unless the client purchases more), so the model will not ever "see" new images, which makes me think that overfitting perhaps be the most desirable thing for the model to achieved (this translates to heavy data augmentation and high number of epochs).
Notice that there's ONLY ONE image available per class (art piece). That's the situation, which cannot change.
The selected programming language is R, mainly the tensorflow and keras3 libraries.
Just for testing purposes, I took a sample of 10 pieces, generated 9 others from each (data augmentation, applying rotation, vertical/horizontal flipping, random saturation factors, random brigthness factors, etc). Later, created 5 positive and 5 negative pairs per each class. Finally, I ran a siamese network but the accuracy seems to be stuck at 49%.
That being said, it's hard for me to find solutions since every documentation relies on either the same cat vs dogs or mnist dataset. My questions are:

Is a siamese netowrk the right algorithm for this purpose?
What can I do to improve the accuracy?


I am not sure about your problem. Since you need to label all your data, if it is static, you have the perfect solution already. I'd guess the actual thing is that only some of the data is labeled. Could you clarify?

@Royi, There's 20+thousand images in a database, each image has its own unique ID. The physical art pieces are distributed all over Spain, each piece should have a sticker, which could be poorly printed, damaged, unreadable (this happens a lot). So, what do I do at a warehouse (an actual place) when ask to identify a piece whose sticker is damaged? should I scroll over 20+thousand images until I find it? Thats the situation.

@Royi, there's only 1 image per art piece available for me. I was thinking about using siamese-networks. In my first and only attemp, I used only 10 images, for each I generated 9 more (data augmentation). After executing the code, the accuracy is stuck at 49%. I have tried different activation methods and different optimizers, but I ended up with the same wacky accuracy metrics.

OK, I think I now get your case. You're not after Object Detection. You're after image clustering / recognition. You have 1 image per object and want to find it in other images in the data set, is that correct?

@Royi, exactly. Thanks. Just think of it as what would you do if the sticker for a specific painting is missing, is blurry, etc..  In order to know its ID, you take a picture of the painting, pass it to the model/algorithm, so it returns the most similar one among the existing pictures in the database.

Please share the number of different ID's in the dataset, number of of labeled images and number of items. So if you have 10 images of 5 cats and 5 dogs you have 2 items though there might be 2 different dogs and 2 different cats so you have 4 ID's. To the least 4 of them must be labelled (1 per ID to the least).

@Royi, in the data base there's approximately 22400 pieces of art (rows) with unique ID, each row has a single reference image associated.

I still don't get your data. It might be better to share some to better explain your situation.
